# Need help on getting highest salary and second highest salary from emp.csv using java

Tags: arraylist

I have one csv file which has 3 entries of empname,emp id,designation and salary 
Robert,33,Manager,12000
Duval,23,Associate,6000
Kierron,33,AD,20000

Using Java program, I like to achieve the highest salary and second highest salary

public class HighSalary {

```
public static void highSalary() throws IOException {
    String record;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/ak/Documents/emp.csv"));

    System.out.println("\t\t  Max Salary Record\n");

    System.out.println(" ------------------------------------------------------------- ");
    System.out.println("|   Name        Age         Desig       Salary        |");
    System.out.println(" ------------------------------------------------------------- ");

    List<List<String>> arlist = new ArrayList<>();
    // List<String> list = Arrays.asList(a);
    int maxSal = 0;

    while ((record = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] words = record.split(",");

        arlist.add(Arrays.asList(words));

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

            if (maxSal <= Integer.parseInt(words[3])) {
                maxSal = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);

            } else {
                maxSal = maxSal;

            }

        }

        System.out.println("From The Salary Largest Number is:" + maxSal);

    }
    br.close();
}
```

}

---

the problem with this code is printing like this as below:
From The Salary Largest Number is:12000
From The Salary Largest Number is:12000
From The Salary Largest Number is:20000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of two separate variables, one for the highest salary, and the other for the second highest salary.  When assigning the highest salary, the previous highest salary should be clobbering the second highest.  When assigning a new second highest, only the previous second highest should be overwritten.

```
Integer highest = null;
Integer second = null;

while ((record = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] words = record.split(",");
    arlist.add(Arrays.asList(words));

    int salary = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
    if (highest == null) {
        highest = salary;
        second = salary;
    }
    else if (salary > highest) {
        second = highest;
        highest = salary;
    }
    else if (salary > second) {
        second = salary;
    }
}

System.out.println("highest salary: " + highest);
System.out.println("second highest salary: " + second);
```

Comment: this helps, how to  Print out the employee details having highest and second highest salary?

Comment: You would need to also keep track of this metadata and capture it when recording a highest and/or second highest salary.  But, you are really asking a new question.  The question you did ask above has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

**System.out.println("From The Salary Largest Number is:" + maxSal);** Keep this outside while loop.